# Чистое ООП на Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ооп

Создал метод, чтобы данные из класса `town` переносились в список и уже из этого списка выбиралась случайным образом. Но создается 5 строк со множеством объектов, и не получается занести в список.

Помогите, пожалуйста!

```
import random
class I_am:
    def __init__(self , money , carrying):
        self.money = money
        self.carrying = carrying

class Town:
    random_town_spisok = []
    def __init__(self , name , ligs):
        self.name = name
        self.ligs = ligs
    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.name)

    def random(self, town):
        Town.random_town_spisok.append(town)
        Town.random_town_spisok = (random.choice(Town.random_town_spisok))
        print(Town.random_town_spisok)



class Product:
    def __init__(self, name, weight, quality, price):
        self.name = name
        self.weight = weight
        self.quality = quality
        self.price = price
    def __repr__(self):
        return (self.name)
        return (self.weight)


# Товар = деньги и грузоподъёмность
    def product_money(self, money, carrying):
        # Проверка на количество денег
        if money.money >= self.price:
            money.money = money.money - self.price
            print(f"Мы купили {self.name} за {self.price} биткоинов, на счету осталось {money.money} биткоинов!")
        else:
            print(f"Кошелек пуст")
            exit()

        #Проверка на грузоподъёмность
        if carrying.carrying >= self.weight:
            carrying.carrying = carrying.carrying - self.weight
        else:
            print(f"Машина загружена")
            exit()

class Event_useful:
    def __init__(self, name, ligs):
        self.name = name
        self.ligs = ligs
    def useful(self):
        pass

class Event_not_useful(Event_useful):
    def not_useful(self):
        pass






info = I_am(100, 70)

towns = [Town(*args) for args in (('Moskov', 100),
                                  ('Almaty',  60),
                                  ('Talgar',  50),
                                  ('Taraz' ,  80),
                                  ('Rostov',  90)
                                 )]
products = [Product(*args) for args in (('Мясо', 10, 1, 30),
                                        ('Сухофрукты', 2, 1,  8),
                                        ('Зерно', 7, 1, 10),
                                        ('Мука' , 8, 1, 10),
                                        ('Ткань', 20, 1, 16),
                                        ('Краска', 20, 1,  7)
                                       )]

events_useful = [Event_useful(*args) for args in (('Обычный день', 5),
                                     ('Ровная дорога', 2),
                                     ('Река', 2),
                                     ('Встретил местного', 6),
                                     )]

events_not_useful = [Event_not_useful(*args) for args in (('Дождь', 2),
                                     ('Телега сломалась', 0),
                                     ('Разбойники ',6)
                                     )]
for prod in products:
    prod.product_money(info, info)
for town in towns:
    town.random(towns)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если надо выбрать случайный город из списка объектов, то вот так:

```
class Town:

    def __init__(self, name, ligs):
        self.name = name
        self.ligs = ligs
        self.random_town_spisok = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def random(self, town):
        self.random_town_spisok.append(town)
        self.random_town_spisok = random.choice(self.random_town_spisok)
        print(self.random_town_spisok)


towns = [Town(*args) for args in (('Moskov', 100),
                                  ('Almaty',  60),
                                  ('Talgar',  50),
                                  ('Taraz' ,  80),
                                  ('Rostov',  90)
                                 )]

random.choice([town.name for town in towns])
```

Вывод:

```
Almaty
```

Если надо сгенерировать список из случайно выбранных городов, то вот так:

```
class Town:

    def __init__(self, name, ligs):
        self.name = name
        self.ligs = ligs
        self.random_town_spisok = []

    def __repr__(self):
        return self.name

    def random(self, town):
        self.random_town_spisok.append(town)
        self.random_town_spisok = random.choice(self.random_town_spisok)
        print(self.random_town_spisok)


towns = [Town(*args) for args in (('Moskov', 100),
                                  ('Almaty',  60),
                                  ('Talgar',  50),
                                  ('Taraz' ,  80),
                                  ('Rostov',  90)
                                 )]

random_towns = []
for _ in range(5): # в данном случае список будет из 5 элементов
    random_towns.append(random.choice([town.name for town in towns]))

print(random_towns)
```

Вывод:

```
['Moskov', 'Taraz', 'Taraz', 'Talgar', 'Taraz']
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Comment: Отметьте ответ как правильный) Нам всем нужен стимул...